# Using gravity to determine world reference frame?

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, gravity

I am working on a pedometer on Android. To improve it, I would love to distillate the vertical force from all the other forces.

Documentation suggests that the orientation sensor should not be used anymore, due to inaccuraccy, so I was looking to something else.

My idea was: Use the 'TYPE_GRAVITY' sensor to determine what real vertical axis is (from core of earth to sky) and then use that information to rotate the TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION data and then only use the wanted axis.

I was wondering, is this possible? Or is it impossible to calculate the rotation needed from a single [x,y,z] gravity vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to approach this from a physics standpoint rather than an Android/programming standpoint:

Let's say the `TYPE_GRAVITY` sensor returns a vector **G** = [x<sub>G</sub>, y<sub>G</sub>, z<sub>G</sub>].

The `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` sensor returns another vector **A** = [x<sub>A</sub>, y<sub>A</sub>, z<sub>A</sub>].

What you're looking for is the magnitude of the projection of **A** onto a unit vector in the direction of **G**.  In other words, how much of **A** is in the direction of **G**?

First we need to get the unit vector in the direction of **G**, which we'll call **G**<sub>unit</sub> (see what I did there?).  To get this, we divide each component of **G** by its magnitude **||G||**, where **||G||** is the square root of the sum of the squares of each component (the distance formula).  Thus,

**G**<sub>unit</sub> = [x<sub>G</sub> / **||G||**, y<sub>G</sub> / **||G||**, z<sub>G</sub> / **||G||**]

The magnitude of the component of **A** in the direction of **G** is then given by computing the dot product:

**A** · **G**<sub>unit</sub> = (x<sub>A</sub> * (x<sub>G</sub> / **||G||**))  +  (y<sub>A</sub> * (y<sub>G</sub> / **||G||**))  +  (z<sub>A</sub> * (z<sub>G</sub> / **||G||**)).

The result is a scalar (not a vector), and that's the quantity you're looking for.

Here's a good wikipedia article for reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection

Comment: Wow, amazing answer...! It's late here now, and I need to study it good before I really understand it, but wow! Going to try it and will report!

Comment: Wow, amazing indeed. It works great! I tested it with the full accelerometer data, and the gravity output kept being at 1G at the Z axis while rotating the device in every possible way. It looks more complicated then it is, since I already was using `||G||` in my code. It simply is indeed the `magnitude`. I will try to add a bounty to this question to award it to you, since this answer is really really outstanding.

Comment: I guess it makes sense that there would be a pre-calculated magnitude associated with the gravity data.  I'm glad I could help!  My background is in physics and I'm still pretty new to Android programming, so I like when my physics background helps me out in unexpected ways!  I think I might dive into this sensor stuff a bit more now.

Comment: Ok, nice. No, the magnitude is not precalculated, but I calculated it earlier for other purposes, so I understood what you were talking about. :)